# F# Strange difference in behavior of two recursive function definitions

Tags: recursion, f#

I am trying to define a power function to compute x^y.

```
let rec powFunA  (x,y) = 
  match (x,y) with
  | (_,0) -> 1
  | (x,y) -> x * powFunA (x,y-1);;
```

and

```
let rec powFunB  x y =
  match y with
  | 0 -> 1
  | y -> x * powFunB x y-1;;
```

The call `powFunA (2,5)` works and as expected gives me 32 as result. But somehow, I don't understand why, the second call `powFunB 2 5` leads to a `StackOverflowException`.

I also came across a definition:

```
let rec power = function
    | (_,0) -> 1.0 (* 1 *)
    | (x,n) -> x * power(x,n-1) (* 2 *)
```

Can you please explain the absence of parameters and the usage of *function* on first line of definition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This stack overflow error has to do with F#'s precedence rules. Consider this expression:

```
powFunB x y-1
```

This expression has some function application and the minus operator. In F# (as in all ML languages), function application has the highest precedence ever. Nothing can be more binding.

Therefore, the above expression is understood by the compiler as:

```
(powFunB x y) - 1
```

That is, function application `powFunB x y` first, minus operator second. Now, I hope, it's easy to see why this results in infinite recursion.

To fix, just apply parentheses to override precedence rules:

```
powFunB x (y-1)
```

---

The "parameterless" definition uses F# syntax for defining multicase functions. It's just a shortcut that allows to write `= function` instead of `x = match x with`. So, for example, the following two function are equivalent:

```
let f a = match a with | Some x -> [x] | None -> []
let g = function | Some x -> [x] | None -> []
```

Just some syntactic sugar, that's all. So the definition you found is exactly equivalent to your first snippet.

Comment: WRT F# operator precedence: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/